# Upload photos to Google Photos API - Error 500

Tags: ajax, filereader, google-photos, google-photos-api

I'm getting the error below while trying to upload media to Google Photos API, following [the docs](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media)

[image: Google Photos API Error]

This is how i retrieve my bytes array:

[image: Retrieve bytes array]

And this is how i make the request:

[image]

I've tried a lot of things and none of it work...

**Note:** I'm consuming other Google Photos API endpoints, such as Get Albums, Create Albums, Get Media and everything work as expected. The upload media is the only one i'm having trouble with.

**Note 2:** The token is being sent correctly.

**Note 3:** All the origin endpoints were configured in the google console (localhost included) so much so that other endpoints are working correctly.

Anyone can give me a light?

Answer (score 0):

I am writing something similar in C# and was able to work with the photo api. My best advice is to double check headers. I hope this helps, additionally I added a postman screenshot of a successful call to the api:

```html
public async Task<GoogleApiResponse> UploadPhoto(StorageFile photo)
        {
            var userInfo = UserInfoVault.GetUserInfo();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", userInfo.AccessToken);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Goog-Upload-File-Name", photo.DisplayName);

            var fileStream = await photo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            var reader = new DataReader(fileStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fileStream.Size);
            byte[] pixels = new byte[fileStream.Size];
            reader.ReadBytes(pixels);

            var httpContent = new ByteArrayContent(pixels);
            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            HttpResponseMessage photoResponse = client.PostAsync(ApiEdnpoints.UploadPhoto, httpContent).Result;
            string strResponse = await photoResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return null;
        }
```

[Postman screenshot of successful call to upload a photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I35lW.png)